# Is it possible to get product id from the list of product from SKStoreProductViewController?

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, storekit

Basically I am getting the list of products from Storekit:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
// Configure View Controller
[storeProductViewController setDelegate:self];
[storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @"APPID"} completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@ with User Info %@.", error, [error userInfo]);
  } else {
    // Present Store Product View Controller
  }
}];
 [self presentViewController:storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when I click on a product on the list. it brings me out of the app and into the app store. Basically I want to display this in app from teh same viewcontroller. Is this even possible? I was thinking of capturing the id and forcing the view to push it onto itself.

Comment: What list of products? `SKStoreProductViewController` only shows a single product that you specify with the `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` key.

Comment: if you put in your publisher id, it generates a list products instead of a product detail.

Comment: Is publisher id different from our vendor id. I tried to use my vendor id and I get an error about being unable to connect to itunes.apple.com. It works fine when I specify a single app id.

Comment: not sure if it's publisher id, it might be the appStoreID for the artist. If you check on the app store there is a link for more from this developer. that link contains the id. It worked for me

Comment: I found what I needed - it's "artistId". I can now display all of my apps in `SKStoreProductViewController`. Thanks. I am now seeing what you are seeing. The in-app `SKStoreProductViewController` shows the list of apps but when you pick one, you get sent to the AppStore app and the `SKStoreProductViewController` is dismissed. There is no way to stay in the app and there is no way to know which product the user selected. I suggest you file an bug/enhancement request with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing, about `SKStoreProductViewController` redirecting to the app-store app is not great behavior, but it doesn't seem there's anyway to override it. You can work around that by doing what many other apps have been doing for a while: create your own 'More Apps' panel that lists all your apps. You can ping the app store HTTP search API from the device, then use the JSON it returns to pull whatever icons/text you need to generate your 'More Apps' list. Then have each individual button in that list open the SKStoreProductViewController. The benefit of this is you'll keep the users in-app, and you'll still have an up-to-date list of all your apps.